# Can a java subclass's private final field be initialized before the super constructor completes?

Tags: java, null, super, construction

I have a pair of classes looking like this;

```
public abstract class Class1 {

//...

    public Class1() {
        //...
        function2();
        //...
    }

    protected abstract void function2();

}

public class Class2 implements Class1 {

    private final OnSomethingListener mOnSomethingListener = new OnSomethingListener() {
        @Override
        onSomething() {
            doThatOtherThing();
        }
    }

    protected void function2() {
        //uses mOnSomethingListener
        //however mOnSomethingListener is null when this function is called from super()
        //...
    }

    public Class2() {
        super();
    }
}
```

I assume the listener is null because I am effectively referencing it from `super()` and it hasn't instantiated yet.  However, I want to make it `final` because, well, it is.  Can I get this field (the listener) to initialize in time without putting it in the superclass (which won't be using the listener, ever)?

Comment: Having correct behaviour should trump "using `final` wherever possible". I'd just use a getter for the listener that lazy-initializes the field. This makes the order of initialization perfectly clear and explicit without relying on a technicality. Alternately, you could have a second initialization function run after the constructors and call `function2()`, but I still don't think it's a better choice than dropping `final`.

Comment: A superclass will be initialized before one of its subclasses is.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11104339/create-an-object-before-the-super-call-in-java

Comment: @Jean-ChristopheFortin: That's a good solution if the superclass needs the object the subclass manages directly. In this case it seems the OP wants the superclass to be unaware of what exactly `function2()` does or needs to run.

Answer (score 5):

Your design is an instance of the "leaked `this` problem" and is an anti-pattern in Java. You should never call out to a publicly overridable method from a constructor.

Comment: A typical way around it would be a two-step procedure where you first instantiate and then initialize.

Comment: This tends to be a problem if you're working with something like Wicket which lives on doing all object initialisation from the constructor. (A sentiment I can understand, having to use separate initialisers feels unnatural.)

Comment: I'm on Android, and I need to add `View`s to a `ViewGroup` hierarchy and sometimes I need to add some extra ones.  I have fixed the actual problem by using the callback in the sub-constructor but I can see why this might be a bad idea, yes!

Comment: @millimoose The right approach is a factory method, which can be viewed from the outside as a single point of initialization. If Wicket doesn't support that, it's a sign of weakness.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Or a sign of not throwing every single pattern there is at your API surface when the tradeoff isn't worth it. The "leaked `this` problem" doesn't occur often enough and is mitigated easily enough with lazy initialisers that it's a valid design choice to not want to make your API fragmented and less intuitive.

Comment: @millimoose Leaked `this` is far from the only use case for a factory method. The Spring framework, for one, has had support for it for many years now. But, since I'm not experienced in Wicket, there may be a specific reason why it's not such a big deal in that particular corner of the Java Universe.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik The reason would be that they prefer to use Java-language constructs over patterns, in the interest of keeping the API straightforward whenever possible. (As do I.) Wicket is heavily geared towards subclassing framework classes, which would be tricky to do if the API surface consisted of factories. (There's nothing stopping you from creating / managing your classes however you with of course.)

Comment: @millimoose I wouldn't expect it to be geared towards factory methods, just to support them for those cases that call for them. I wouldn't go so far to refuse `static` methods the status of Java language constructs, BTW (since that's all a factory method is, in terms of Java constructs).

Answer (score 3):

Short answer - no.  A superclass' constructor, field initialisers and instance initialisers are always called before the subclass'.

The order of calls is formally defined in [section 8.8.7.1 of the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.7.1).  Summarising the relevant last parts (where `S` is the superclass and `C` is the subclass):

> After determining the immediately enclosing instance of i with respect to S (if any), evaluation of the superclass constructor invocation statement proceeds by evaluating the arguments to the constructor, left-to-right, as in an ordinary method invocation; and then invoking the constructor.
>
> Finally, if the superclass constructor invocation statement completes normally, then all instance variable initializers of C and all instance initializers of C are executed. If an instance initializer or instance variable initializer I textually precedes another instance initializer or instance variable initializer J, then I is executed before J.

So when the superclass constructor runs, the subclass and all its fields are completely uninitialised.  It's bad practice to call overridden methods from a constructor for this reason.  You're essentially letting a reference to the object "escape" from its constructor, which means all the guarantees of construction are off (including things like final fields changing value, etc.).

Calling an *abstract* method from a constructor is almost always the wrong thing to do.  Depending on the implementation of the method in the subclass(es) you might get away with it in some case (i.e. if the method does not depend on any state at all), but it will almost certainly cause a hard-to-debug failure at some point.

For example, would you expect there to be a difference between:

```
protected String function2() {
    return "foo";
}
```

and

```
private final String foo = "foo";

protected String function2() {
    return foo;
}
```

Analysing problems like this is hard, because they break the mental model of how classes work.  Best to avoid this situation altogether.

Answer (score 2):

super classes are always initialised before subclasses.  Only static fields of a sub class can be initialised first.

You can call an overridden method from the super class which then accesses a field which is not initialised. This is considered bad practice.